# Get N last posts tagged with T in Ghost JS

Tags: javascript, ghost-blog, ghost

**My Problem.**

I am creating a blog with Ghost JS and, in the `home.hbs` page, I need to include two separated summary lists containing last posts published in my blog. The first list should show last `n1` posts tagged with tag `t1` whilst the second one list would show last `n2` posts tagged with tag `t2`. For instance `n1=8 t1=book` should stand for `get last 8 published books in my blog` and `n2=3 t2=song` for `get last 3 published songs in my blog`.

**My Approach.**

As I am not sure if my problem can be solve declaratively by means of contexts and helpers, I am trying to activate the Beta features and I am using the REST API provided by ghost. I have read the API docs but I don't know how I should express my query. I am checking queries like the following, but I fail when expressing the filter condition (get just those posts tagged by `T`):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(
       ghost.url.api('posts', {
          limit: '3',
          include: 'tags, author',
          filter: 'tags:song', // ???
          order: 'count.posts DESC'
       })
    ).done(onSuccess);
});
```

**My Question.**

My question is twofold. Is there some approach to my problem that let solve it in a declarative way with contexts and helpers? If not, how should I code my query in the AJAX call to the API to get the last `N` posts tagged with tag `T`?

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use the new {{get}} helper.

https://themes.ghost.org/docs/get

Something along these lines would work for tag clouds.

`{{#get "tags" limit="3" include="count.posts" order="count.posts desc"}}`

As for the posts with tags you can do this.

`{{#get "posts" limit="3" include="tags, author" filter="tag:song"}}`

Comment: Thanks JTWebMan but I am not sure how can I use that helper to get the info. Could you please write the query expression required for my problem?

Comment: @JavierVélez I updated the answer with so helper options